# Como armazenar o resultado em uma variável para usar depois? - PHP

Tags: php, variáveis

Como posso fazer para armazenar o resultado desse código dentro de uma variável? Quero armazenar em uma variável para que eu possa exibir o resultado a qualquer momento utilizando `<?php echo $row['resultado']; ?>` por exemplo.

Segue o código abaixo e o DEMO no ExtendsClass para testes:
**https://extendsclass.com/php-bin/4eb56d4** *(Clicar em RUN para executar)*

```
<?php

$data1 = '2021-02-23 00:00:00';
$data2 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("-3 hours", strtotime("now")));
 
$unix_data1 = strtotime($data1);
$unix_data2 = strtotime($data2);

$nHoras   = ($unix_data2 - $unix_data1) / (60 * 60);
$nMinutos = (($unix_data2 - $unix_data1) % (60 * 60)) / 60;
 
printf('%02d:%02d', $nHoras, $nMinutos);

// Exemplo do que preciso, mas dessa forma não dá certo:
// $resultado = printf('%02d:%02d', $nHoras, $nMinutos);
// echo $resultado;

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a função [`sprintf`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.sprintf.php), que retorna a string ao invés de imprimir.

```php
<?php

$data1 = '2021-02-23 00:00:00';
$data2 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("-3 hours", strtotime("now")));
 
$unix_data1 = strtotime($data1);
$unix_data2 = strtotime($data2);

$nHoras   = ($unix_data2 - $unix_data1) / (60 * 60);
$nMinutos = (($unix_data2 - $unix_data1) % (60 * 60)) / 60;
 
// printf('%02d:%02d', $nHoras, $nMinutos);

$resultado = sprintf('%02d:%02d', $nHoras, $nMinutos);
echo "Hora: {$resultado}"

?>
```

[**DEMO**](https://ideone.com/q2K2Q5)